# How to check if an image is incompleted (missing data)?

Tags: php, image, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface

So I have this program on my Raspberry Pi that is supposed to regularly backup my blog onto it. I'm currently running it manually. Today my internet connection was extremely slow so I killed the program in the middle of the download. It did however save all of the downloaded data it managed to get and now my program reads that the image exists and skips it. Sure I can delete it and have the program to re-download it for me but I want to make sure this doesn't happen again in the future.

I'm working with PHP on the server side. The command I use for saving the images is

```
copy($url, $path);
```

I'm doing a very simple check if a file exists.

```
if(!file_exists($path))
```

The image files on my server are of PNG and JPG file formats.

---

Dumb me, I forgot to write what I had tried. I have found multiple questions like this but their solutions don't seem to work. All of them claim that `imagecreatefromtype($img)` should return false in those situations.

PHP manual:

> Returns an image resource identifier on success, FALSE on errors.

I'm getting "Premature end of JPEG file" which seemed like it should have returned false but it didn't. It returns the same value as if the image was not corrupt,

```
Resource id #6
```

---

It would be great to have some sort of quick way of determining if the images is whole or not.

Comment: I don't know what part of your code determines whether or not to download a file, but you could try checking file size as well as modification time. This should at least catch partial writes.

Comment: I simply use if(!file_exists($path)). Now what do you mean by checking the file size? Is it possible to know the file size of an external image without fully downloading it? I had this idea of running multiple tests calculating the file size by doing width x height x bitsperpixel as I am provided with the width, height and the url of the images. But that also might give false results as I don't know the exact bit depth. Or I could calculate the average bit depth of all of the images with the same format and then compare it to others and see how much they differ. But different compression tho.

Comment: you could do a Head request to get the actual file size and use php file size to check locally. This can also provide you with the modification date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download to a temporary file (on the same partition), and rename the file when the download has finished. As renaming a file is an atomic operation - as long as source and destination are located on the same partition - this would make sure that the image is valid.

Like this:

```
// Create a tempfile
$tempfile = tempnam("/path/to/tempfolder", "download");

// Download to a tempfile
$ret = copy($url, $tempfile);

if($ret) {
    // Move tempfile to final location.
    // This is an atomic operation (with the restrictions named above)
    rename($tempfile, "path/to/image.png");
} else {
    unlink($tempfile);
    die("Download broken");
}
```

Even if the copy does not finish - because of a power outage or whatever, the final image will not getting created in a broken state.

Comment: This is such a simple and powerful solution. This will really prevent that from happening in the future. This does help me a lot, but the original question was how to determine if an image is broken/missing data. As much as I would like to accept this answer, it doesn't answer the given question :c

Comment: Why it should be broken if `copy` succeeds?

Comment: I'm not saying it wont, I'm just interested to see if there's a way to check if the image is corrupted or not as that was the original question. I totally agree that your code will prevent that from happening ever again in the future, but I'm interested in knowing how to determent if an image is already broken on my server. I currently have around 7000 images that were downloaded in a very primitive way. There could be other images like that so it would be great to check them all without having to download each and single one of them again and checking if they match.

Answer (score 1):

in your question you used a PNG image, that has a Checksum (CRC32) you can check.
if the checksum pass, then most likely the image is whole.

the PNG Specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5CRC-algorithm

Comment: I have mostly JPGs on my server. As much as Google shows, JPG files don't have anything like checksums in them. But this is a good idea for PNG files.

Comment: you can always add your own checksum to  a JPEG.

Comment: That might work. If I download an image and after it finishes downloading I make a checksum and add that record to the database. Then I'd know if the image was downloaded successfully. Though this would require an extra table in the database and that table would be practically useless in the future. hek2mgl answer is probably still better in that situation, though that would still only prevent that from happening in the future and wouldn't help me identifying broken images that I (probably) already have on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to think up of a solution. This is a code that should detect incomplete image files. **Supports only PNG and JPEG formats** as I don't currently need other format support. It works by checking the JPEG's SOI and EOI and the PNG's IDHR and IEND.

You can pass two arguments to this function - the file name and if the JPEG has more JPEGs in itself.

If the `$jpeg_in_jpeg` is specified when calling the function, a slower script will be executed to check if SOI count is equal to EOI count, hence the file is whole. Though this would be only needed if a file would end at the inner JPEG's EOI but you need to be extremely unlucky for that to happen.

---

**Update**: I realized that parsing all of the data into bytes and into an array and then comparing values is extremely slow. An 1.145 MB JPEG image would be checked in 26 whole seconds! But now I changed it to `preg_match_all()` and now it's ~800 times faster. The numbers in question are (in seconds):

26,64180707931471 (the old method) / 0.032716035842896 (the new method) = 814,3348175570528 (times faster).

If you really need speed and don't think that you will ever get so unlucky that the file would end at the inner JPEG's EOI, use the faster method by not specifying `$jpeg_in_jpeg`. The speed would increase by ~2,6 times if compared to the new `$jpeg_in_jpeg` method. The numbers are (in seconds):

0.032716035842896 (`$jpeg_in_jpeg = true`) / 0.012523889541626 (`$jpeg_in_jpeg` not specified) = 2,612290353907259 (times faster)

Keep in mind this was all tested on a Raspberry Pi B model. The function's execution time should be a lot shorter on a normal server.

```
function isImageComplete($file_name, $jpeg_in_jpeg = null){
    $image_type = @exif_imagetype($file_name);

    if($image_type)
        $data = file_get_contents($file_name);

    if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
        if($jpeg_in_jpeg){
            #Note: Some JPEG images have even more JPEGs inside of them (have multiple SOI and EOI). This check is slow, though eliminates the very small chance of detecting thumbnail's EOI as the file's ending.

            $soi = chr(255).chr(216);
            $eoi = chr(255).chr(217);

            $results = preg_match_all("/$soi|$eoi/", $data, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

            $soi_count = 0;
            $eoi_count = 0;

            foreach($out[0] as $o)
                if(ord($o[0]).ord($o[1]) == "255216")
                    $soi_count++;
                elseif(ord($o[0]).ord($o[1]) == "255217")
                    $eoi_count++;

            if($soi_count == $eoi_count && $soi_count > 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        else{
            $soi = substr($data, 0, 2);
            $eoi = substr($data, -2);

            $pair_count = 0;

            if(ord($soi[0]).ord($soi[1]) == "255216")
                $pair_count++;
            if(ord($eoi[0]).ord($eoi[1]) == "255217")
                $pair_count++;

            if($pair_count == 2)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $a_idhr = array();
        $a_iend = array();

        $idhr = substr($data, 0, 8);
        $iend = substr($data, -12);

        foreach(str_split($idhr) as $char){ 
            array_push($a_idhr, ord($char)); 
        }

        foreach(str_split($iend) as $char){ 
            array_push($a_iend, ord($char)); 
        }

        if(implode('', $a_idhr) == '13780787113102610' && implode('', $a_iend) == '0000736978681746696130')
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1; #File format not supported by the function.
    }
}
```

---

While playing around with my RPi, I had discovered that I had an another JPEG image within the JPEG file, though `exif_thumbnail()` didn't return anything. I think you could try checking if `exif_thumbnail()` returns something and then use the slower `$jpeg_in_jpeg`. But as I discovered, it doesn't return the JPEG inside. It could be that it's not being treated as a thumbnail but as something else. Keep in mind that this was the first time I delved into image file formats so I know very little.